# Last visited hint on the questions page

Tags: feature-request, homepage

If I visited a question before, it would be helpful to display a hint showing when the page was last visited.

Right now the link is highlighted with a different color, but only if I'm visiting from the same browser & PC. So this is standard functionality of a browser, not something coming from Stackoverflow.

I suggest replacing this:

[image]

with this:

[image]

Then I can see this information when accessing SO from different devices. I believe it should help improve site navigation - avoid round-trip to questions that users have already visited and acted upon.

An extension to this idea is to include total number of visits by YOU:

[image]

If no visits were made yet, it should look the same as now (screenshot #1 from the above).

Comment: "4 visits" is redundant, you have *views* counter at the left.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: No I meant to count only your views, not total views by all users.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how it can be useful. Usually when you visit a question, you visit it because it's interesting for you. 
If that's the case, you're supposed to remember that you already been there. If not, it will take you less than a second to go back to previous page (by hitting the backslash or the back button in your browser).

Comment: I appreciate your opinion. But I have to disagree. Depending on the number of events in your life, you may not remember anything from 2hrs ago. Also, not all questions are worth remembering, IMHO. Sometimes you just went there to cast a close vote, or downvote and leave. Bad questions are reality, which we have to deal with. You are right though - going back and forth is fast. But it's tiring for the brain.